# Blazor ServerSide 'Websocket Connection to '{url}' failed occured' when host with Nginx Proxy

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, websocket, blazor-server-side, nginx-reverse-proxy

We are deploying the Blazor ServerSide app with the Nginx Proxy in a Linux Docker environment.
Other functions work well, but an error occurs when accessing the signalR Websocket.
A 504 (Gateway Time-out) error occurs every 60 seconds and attempts to reconnect each time.

[websocket_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgFzi.png)

My Blazor Startup setting:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        app.UseRouting();

        HiCommon.HostRootPath = env.WebRootPath;
        HiCommon.Instance.Configuration = this.Configuration;
        
        app.UseDevExpressServerSideBlazorReportViewer();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub(options =>
            {
                options.WebSockets.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 1, 1);
                options.LongPolling.PollTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
                //options.Transports = HttpTransportType.LongPolling;
                //options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                //options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
                //options.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            });
            endpoints.MapHub<BroadcastHub>(BroadcastHub.HubUrl);
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

My Nginx Config:

```
    server {
    listen 4000 default_server;
    listen [::]:4000 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ @staticsites;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            # WebSocket
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass https://{url}:8001;
    }

    location @staticsites{
            proxy_pass https://{url}:8001;
    }
   }
```

As you can see from above
The Blazor Server App operates on 8001 (https) and 8000 (http) ports
and the Nginx Proxy Server operates on 4000 (http) and 3000 (future designated as https ports).

if you look at the error, the Blazor Server App is attempting to connect to the Websocket from the Blazor Server App to the port on the Nginx Server.
I think the http connection is well connected through Proxy to Port 8001 on the Blazer Server App, but for some reason, the Websocket connection port is connected to the Port on the Proxy Server.

when I ran the Blazer Server App in Debug mode and checked the Console, I saw that the WebSocket was connected to the port of the Blazer Server App.

[websocket_success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apvED.png)

I think can solve it if i can control the port that connects at the time of the Websocket Handshake, but does the solution of this problem match the way I think?
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: If you implement `Websocket Handshake` to handle it does it encounter any further issues? Have you implemented the approach you shared so far?

Comment: I don't understand what it means to implement a Websocket handshake My project has not made any additional settings for the SignalR connection. What I understand is that when a client connects to the Blazor Server Side App, there are many ways to create a SignalR connection and achieve it. One of them is WebSocket, and I understand that the most efficient connection method is WebSocket, so Blazor tries to connect through WebSocket as a top priority.
Is there anything that I misunderstand?

Comment: Apparently, your concept is correct hence you still could have a look at this [`official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server)